# I cannot se how the device is a buck charger when charging and a boost on the output

Tags: lithium-ion, datasheet, charger

I cannot se how the device is a buck charger when charging and a boost on the output.
Am I stupid or is the datasheet wrong?

"5A Single Cell Li-Ion Switching Battery Charger with Direct
Charge, Power Path Management and USB OTG Boost Mode
"
https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9468/DS9468-01.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [This answer might help you understand around the problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353802/is-it-possible-to-get-a-high-efficiency-buck-boost-converter-by-switching-betwee/353833#353833)

Comment: @Andyaka there is only one low side switch, what I can se, so itsn't a H-bridge configuration.

Answer (score 4):

**Buck Regulator for Charging Battery**.
 =  Stepdown from 5V to Battery (CC then 4.2V then cutoff)

**Boost Regulator as OTG** (on-the-go USB power)
 = Step-Up from Battery to USB or 3~4V  to 5V

It is consistent and correct.

I have redrawn the switches to show more clearly the topology used.

[image]

Comment: so the input("vbus") is the output in Boost OTG mode?

Comment: Yes Vbus is the output in Boost mode.  Thus the design needs a Full bridge to change Vbat current direction and a bridge to swap PWM from series (Buck) to shunt mode.(Boost)

Comment: They don't really want you to understand how they designed it, just to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A synchronous buck converter, operating in continuous mode, will work just fine in reverse.  In a lossless circuit, the PWM ratio plus the continuous conduction in the inductor enforces a voltage ratio from input to output, but lets current go either way.  It's just a matter of how you arrange your control circuit.

Comment: So the input (Vbus) will be the output in boost mod?

Comment: I assume so -- it'd pretty much have to be, and it would fit with the notion of having a box that either takes 5V in and charges a battery, or puts 5V out.  The datasheet is a bit light on that sort of detail.